# how to pull json data from a server/url and set equal to a variable?

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts, json-server

I currently have a gauge chart from highcharts working with data that I directly input but now I am trying to transition to pulling the data (json fromat) from a server that is hosted through `json-server --watch livePSAD.json --port 8000`  this is the chart that I currently have https://jsfiddle.net/IzzyStrauch/9zuewk18/18/

```
series: [
      {
        name: "Speed",
        data: [85],
        tooltip: {
          valueSuffix: " RPM"
        }
      }
    ],
```

I am currently trying to figure out a way to set the data part of the series equal to http://localhost:8000/f0s
which looks like this

```
[
  55
]
```

and have it live update every 3 seconds which I know I could possibly do through enablePolling: true but i cant event get it to just pull the static number of 55 from the url.

```
if (!chart.renderer.forExport) {
      setInterval(function () {
        var lg = 50;
        var hg = 120;
        var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
          axis = chart.yAxis[0];

        axis.update({
          plotBands: [
            {
              from: 0,
              to: lg,
              color: "red" // green
            },
            {
              from: lg,
              to: hg,
              color: "green" // yellow
            },
            {
              from: hg,
              to: 200,
              color: "red" // red
            }
          ]
        });
      }, 3000);
    }
  }
```

I then want to set the variable lg to http://localhost:8000/f0lg and hg to http://localhost:8000/f0hg which
lg looks like this

```
[
  30
]
```

hg looks like this

```
[
  70
]
```

and I want to have those also pull from that url every 3 seconds

Any thoughts as to how this might be possible?

Using the checked solution I now have all the variables entering and changing the chart but the tick marks are all wonky
this is the new code
https://jsfiddle.net/IzzyStrauch/1rx3tyjp/9/

(for some reason it works on jsfidle but not in my code where I am using it but it is exactly the same other than I have more charts on my page/code)
Any thoughts on why this could be?

Comment: After doing some more digging and testing I have tried var obj;
`fetch('http://localhost:8000/lg')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data1 => obj = data1)
  .then(() => console.log(obj))` and `let b1data;    
fetch('http://localhost:8000/B1').then(
        function(u){ return u.json();}
      ).then(
        function(json){
          b1data = json;
        }
      )` but I couldn't get either to work for me

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Please add all attempts to your question by editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this demo that shows how to fetch a JSON data and initialize the chart: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rdn4fyb7/

```
fetch("https://api.npoint.io/6f74f002ed847e39cc3c")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    //check how the fetched data looks like
    console.log(data)

    //create chart
    Highcharts.chart('container', {

      series: [{
                type: 'column',
        data: data.data
      }]
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thank you this is working for me except that now the tick marks on my gauge are now crooked and not even I will add to the question what I see. Do you have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: @ChillHat your demo doesn't work because it is impossible to fetch data from your localhost. Please upload the data sample to some online data storage.